# Was this part of Berserker Series by Saberhagen?

Tags: story-identification, berserker

I read many books from Berserker series but now can't even recall all the ones that I read. During that time I also read many different Sci-Fi books like Damned Series, and other series that I don't even remember and everything kind of mixed together. I'm trying to figure out if the following is from Berserker series or not.

Man (if he could be called that)who is part machine stationed alone on some space ship or maybe just a station on some planet. From description it was as if he body parts were in separate containers or he was comprised on different containers that made up his body. This story was about him and how he was waging war against machines. Well at some point a female character arrives there and at some point she falls in love with him.

As I recall, some books of Beserker series were made up of very short stories that were not connected. Back in 90s in Siberia we had very limited was of entertaining, mine was reading all Sci-Fi books that all local libraries had. So have to take in consideration that description could be off because it was translated to Russian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be the answer:
**Brother Assassin** by Fred Saberhagen ([http://www.amazon.com/Brother-Assassin-Berserker-Series-Book/dp/0812536428](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812536428))

Humans battled Berserkers by sending remotely controlled robots back in time.  Robot controls looked like the controls used in Pacific Rim.

IIRC Berserker robots looked like wolves while human controlled robots looked like robotic humans.

The book was broken up into shorter stories about multiple engagements spread out through time.

> On the planet Sirgol the death machines have a unique and sublte mode
>   of attack. Now, the time and place of the next attack has been
>   pinpointed--the berserkers will try to eliminate Vincent Vincento, an
>   early genius whose loss will cost mankind a hundred years of progress
>   in the physical sciences. Derron Odegard, one of the elite corps of
>   Time Operatives, has the toughest assignment in Sirgol's
>   history--protect Vincento at any cost.